# Does D/D/D oracle King d'arc's effect work on all card effects that take life Points?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

What I want to know is, will [D/D/D Oracle King d'Arc](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/D/D/D_Oracle_King_d%27Arc)'s effect work on cards like [Exchange of Spirit](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Exchange_of_the_Spirit) and [The Winged Dragon of Ra](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Winged_Dragon_of_Ra)'s second effect as they state you must "pay" life points not "take damage".

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Paying lifepoints and taking damage are two different things, just like an effect that sends a monster to the graveyard is different from an effect that destroys a monster. The wording is important. Because the word that the card text uses usually matters, paying lifepoints for any reason will not equate to taking damage for cards like D'Arc. You can read more about taking damage vs. paying lifepoints [here.](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Damage)

Any cards that specifically inflicts damage to yourself will work, however. Blazing Mirror Force and Ring of Destruction both fit the bill, while also offering useful destruction effects. If you want a full list of cards that do this, you can find it [here.](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Damages_you)

Comment: *"Paying lifepoints and taking damage are two different things"* - I'd like to highlight this part, which basically sums it up. The wording is indeed specific for a reason.